# Built-in for getting list element or default?

Tags: r

Is there a built-in function or a (popular) package in R that will return a specific list element, or a default?

Example:

```
> l <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
> getElementOrDefault(l, 'b', 0)
[1] 2
> getElementOrDefault(l, 'd', 0)
[1] 0
```

I am looking for the actual name for `getElementOrDefault`.
I know it is not hard to write such a function from scratch, but using a built-in has its advantages. So please do not answer by writing the code for `getElementOrDefault`.

Comment: What is "a default"? BTW. You could easily extract an element using `[` or `[[`  Why bother another function?

Comment: No, afaik there is no such build-in function. I don't see the advantage of a build-in function over a user-defined function for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***tl;dr:*** There’s no built-in solution but R lends itself more naturally to something *extending* its accessor syntax, rather than replacing it. If you’re impatient, skip ahead until after the horizontal separator.

> using a built-in has its advantages

This is a fair point (as you’ve explained in the comments) but since there doesn’t seem to be the default this point is rather moot. However, with a bit of care we can define such an operation to behave just the same way a built-in operation would.

At its simplest, we just forward the indexing to the `[[` operator – which *is* built-in – and thus avoid all complications arising from having to handle different types of indices:

```
item_or_default = function (list, item, default = NULL) {
    value = list[[item]]
    if (is.null(value)) default else value
}
```

The only caveat here is that indexing via `[[` is usually recursive but here we only support a single index.

This approach cannot distinguish between missing values and `NULL`, since the built-in indexing operations don’t make this distinction either. This can be fixed by checking whether the index is out of bounds if it’s numeric, or whether it’s missing if it’s a character string. The implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

As an alternative, we could override the existing `[[` operator and augment it by a `default` argument:

```
`[[` = function (x, ...) {
    `[[` = previous_definition('[[')
    if (class(x) != 'list')
        return(x[[...]])

    # NB: length of index can be > 1, to allow for recursive indexing.
    args = list(...)
    default = args$default
    args$default = NULL
    value = do.call(`[[`, c(list(x), args))
    if (is.null(value)) default else value
}

previous_definition = function (name) {
    # Skip the parent environment of the calling frame.
    get(name, envir = parent.env(parent.env(parent.frame())))
}
```

This is mostly straightforward. Note that we have to dispatch the operator manually depending of the type of `x`, since overriding `[[.list` doesn’t work (even though the documentation claims that the operator is generic). `previous_definition` supplies us with the previous definition of `[[`, ignoring the redefinition. We thus avoid calling the same function recursively.

The function is defined intentionally such that the `default` argument must be *named*, to allow recursive indexing, and to avoid confusion. As an example:

```
test = list(a = 1)
test[['a', default = 42]]
# 1
test[['b', default = 42]]
# 42
test[['a', 42]]
# Error …: Incorrect number of subscripts
```

---

But finally, **all these solutions are somewhat odd**. I wouldn’t use any of them in actual code. Instead, I use the following:

```
`%or%` = function(a, b) {
    cmp = function(a,b) if (identical(a, FALSE) ||
                            is.null(a) ||
                            is.na(a) ||
                            is.nan(a) ||
                            length(a) == 0) b else a

    if (length(a) > 1)
        mapply(cmp, a, b)
    else
        cmp(a, b)
}
```

This allows me to write the following code (and more):

```
test$a %or% 42
# 1
test$b %or% 42
# 42
```

Comment: You mean `%in%` not `in`.

Comment: @agstudy You do not need `{}`, and indeed using them here is nonsense. And I don’t see why this solution is not the “R way”. You could certainly redefine `[[` but you couldn’t use it conveniently: how would you pass the extra argument? `mylist[[name, default]]`? That syntax is rather un-intuitive. In fact, in my *actual* code I’ve done this differently: I’ve defined an operator `%or%` which allows me to write `list$name %or% default`. Now *that* is the R way of solving this.

Comment: @Roland You can in fact trivially redefine it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right. I've just tried it successfully. However, I'm not sure that it wouldn't create problems with functions depending on `[[`'s standard behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The first solution will clearly be enough in most cases, but (the current state of) the second, more appropriate one will not work when list items don't have names, or if you want to use a numeric index. If you handle that as well, the function will be longer and more involved. This is one of the reasons I said that "using a built-in has its advantages": Either you write a short function that is not quite right, or it gets longer, takes a while to write and to test out, and then either you keep duplicating the code, or end up including it in a new package...

Comment: An alternative to `item %in% names(list)` is `exists(item, list)`. It will error out unless all list items have a name.

Comment: @Roland Have a look at the updated answer. This `[[` redefinition is a safe substitute for the existing one. Furthermore, it won’t interfere with (properly implemented) packages since those have their own namespace.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `[[` is generic. However, as for `[` there are special classes which are handled by the primitive prior to method dispatch.

Comment: @Geza Fair point, but, taken to its extreme conclusion, this opens the door to bad code: standard packages will *never* cover all general purpose functionality – they cannot. So user code must provide some of this general-purpose functionality on its own; and if it doesn’t do that, the resulting code is objectively worse because it leaves out opportunities for abstraction.

Comment: @KonradRudolp I agree with that, definitely. All I am saying is that I prefer built-ins when available, but we should definitely not provide abstractions for functionality that is not built-in. Thanks for doing just that. I of course added +1, and will accept your answer in a little while if noone finds a built-in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Update Oct. 2022*

The package [rlang](https://rlang.r-lib.org/index.html) defines two functions, very similar to [Konrad's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561737/6723896),

1. `%||%` - "[op-null-default](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/op-null-default.html)"
2. `%|%` - "[op-na-default](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/op-na-default.html?q=op-na#null)"

For OP's question, getting a default value if the indexing returns `NULL` would look like:

```r
library(rlang)
l <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
l$a %||% 0    # 1
l$d %||% 0    # 0
```

The other function `%|%` vectorizes replacement of `NA` values,

```r
c("a", "b", NA, "c") %|% "default"
# c("a", "b", "default", "c")
```

It's noted in the `%|%` documentation that this function may move to another package, "[funs](https://github.com/tidyverse/funs)" which is under development and will be deprecated in "rlang" when the other package matures.